# How to Manually Update Azure DevOps Services self-hosted agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-agent

Trying to update with UI command from the web portal  the self-hosted agent i get the following error:

> [2023-01-22 08:49:33Z INFO Agent] Refresh message received, kick-off selfupdate background process.
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO SelfUpdater] Version '2.214.1' of 'agent' package available in server.
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO SelfUpdater] Current running agent version is 2.213.2
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO SelfUpdater] An update is available.
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Agent update in progress, do not shutdown agent.
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Downloading 2.214.1 agent
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\agent\bin'
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'C:\agent'
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Work': 'C:\agent_work'
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO SelfUpdater] Attempt 1: save latest agent into C:\agent_work_update\agent1.zip.
> [2023-01-22 08:49:34Z INFO SelfUpdater] Download agent: begin download
> [2023-01-22 08:49:55Z WARN SelfUpdater] Failed to get package 'C:\agent_work_update\agent1.zip' from 'https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.214.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.214.1.zip'. Exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishGetStreamAsync(Task`1 getTask)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.SelfUpdater.DownloadLatestAgent(CancellationToken token)
> [2023-01-22 08:49:55Z INFO SelfUpdater] Attempt 2: save latest agent into C:\agent_work_update\agent1.zip.

TRIED THE FOLLOWING

1. trying to download manually - works.
2. trying to put the downloaded file in the C:\agent_work_update\agent1.zip. - does not work.
3. Testing download with powershell  `Invoke-WebRequest "https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.214.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.214.1.zip" -OutFile "C:\Windows\Temp\archive.zip"` - works .
4. Download with powershell altanate command `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.214.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.214.1.zip", "C:\Windows\Temp\archive1.zip")` - works